# Recommendations for basement insulation where studs do not touch the concrete walls?

Tags: insulation, basement-insulation

I'm working on our basement reno, and am looking for recommendations to insulate. We are in NE Kansas, Climate Zone 5.  The basement is below ground.

We currently have a reflective foil bubble insulation installed against the concrete wall. This was installed prior to us owning the house, but based on products I've looked up it is about an R-3.
[image]
[image]
The majority of the stud walls has a gap between the studs and the concrete.

My current plan was to staple up plastic sheeting (vapor barrier) on the backside of the stud, hang R-13 faced insulation (fiber glass), and wrap the inside of the stud with plastic.

Is this a good plan or is there better (and possibly cheaper) ways of insulating?

Comment: I would not add the plastic sheeting.  You already have one vapor barrier/retarder in the foil.  You don't want two vapor barriers.

Comment: Is you basement below ground, above ground, some of both?

Comment: The basement is below ground, I'll add that to the description.

Comment: So I could simply hang insulation between the studs and be good?

Comment: I would only add the additional insulation to the upper ~36" of the wall.  Once you get below the frost line, the ground temperature is a relatively constant 50 deg F, more or less.  The R-3 that's in place should be fine for that part of the wall.  What does you local jurisdiction require?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to keep the aluminized bubble wrap?

Comment: Mostly the cost. The radiant barrier was already installed in the basement when we bought the house.